# Интерфейсы в PHP

Tags: ооп, php

Можно ли в PHP задавать константы в интерфейсах? Если да, то как к ним обращаться из классов, реализующих интерфейс?

Answer (score 1):

Уже выяснил, что можно. Обращаюсь

```
класс_интерфейса::Имя_константы
```

И все работает!

Answer (score -1):

Нет, интерфейс - это набор абстрактных методов.